# How to get click event to do my custom code on SharePoint List 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I create the list when user open that item after that he edit this item i want to perform custom code on that how to get this click event?[image]

Comment: Do you need to perform custom code after user clicked on edit item or do you need to programmatically trigger edit item from JS code?

Comment: I need to perform custom code after user clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description , I think you don't need to care about Edit Button,

- Just open your `editform.aspx` page in a new window ,
- Edit your page
- Add script editor.
- Add your code.

Once you click Edit button , it should now show `editform.aspx` then the custom code at script editor should be run.

Meanwhile, If you are using SSOM via C# you can develop an EventReceiver before item updated `SPItemEventReceiver.ItemUpdating` to handles the synchronous event that occurs before an item is changed.

Check an example at [Developing an Event Receiver for the ItemUpdating event](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/event-receivers-walkthrough4/)

Comment: I follow your step and add the this code which post by siddharth   $("a[id='Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.EditItem-Large']").click()

Answer (score 1):

But as per my analysis, this might not work. because ribbon elements are being control by ribbon framework which is loaded at client side.Enabling/disabling, redirecting etc will be overridden by this in whatever case you do.

Though for sake of question, you can use below code to bind jquery click event to that button.

```
    $("a[id='Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Manage.EditItem-Large']").click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
return false;
});
```